"Main" panel wiring
At my property the power company installed the meter with a box below it with a 200 AMP breaker.  There are lugs inside to attach wires directly to the bar so they feed directly from that breaker.  So.....does this make then the house panel a subpanel?  It is about 150 ft from the Pole.  Located in Minnesota.




Since you have breakers other than the main here, yes, you need a 4-wire feeder to the house, and yes, the house is going to be a sub-panel with isolated neutral and ground.
There are some cases where a 200A breaker at the pole is labeled as "Emergency Shutoff" "Not main service disconnect" and the feeder to the house can be 3-wire, (where the main will be labeled as "Service Disconnect") but not (AIUI) if there's anything else fed from the same panel.

Given the distance should it also have a grounding rod?

Every separate building requires a grounding electrode system (other than some exceptions for low-amp circuits to e.g. sheds.) That connects to the ground, not the neutral, everywhere but the main panel. If your concrete contractor is good, they should put in a concrete encased electrode (Ufer ground) which is far more effective than a ground rod, or the typical pair of ground rods (that are cheaper & faster than measuring the resistance of one ground rod and meet code minimum.)

It depends.
What they gave you is called an "All-in-one" (meter+main+breakers) - but more specifically it's a type called a "Ranch panel" or "Trailer panel" which aside from 4-12 breaker spaces, also has "thru lugs" to carry the full power onward to another panel.
If it was only a disconnect, then you could declare it to be "not the main panel aka service equipment" by marking it according to NEC 230.85.
But what if it is more?  Certain loads are allowed on the utility side of the service equipment/disconnect.  NEC 230.82 breaks those down.

Meters (utility or yours)
Transfer switches and generator interlocks
Surge protectors
Solar, wind, hydro, X2G (anything to Grid) including battery storage
Energy storage systems (literally but very arguably, EV charging)
Equipment associated with the above, like CT clamps

Of course that's not what ranch/trailer panels are typically used for, generally people pull power off them for local receptacles, power to a shed, wellhouse, etc.  Those do in fact make your panel "the main panel"/service equipment/disconnect.
